# Heroku Node.JS App Not Deploying

Tags: node.js, heroku

So this is my first time using Heroku to deploy a node app. I have been encountering this issue:

[image]
[image]

I have no idea what is going on I have index file in the root folder and my localhost port is 5000. Any help would be greatly be appreciated.

**Structure of Files**

[image]

**Package.json**
[image]

Comment: can you update your question with the structure of your directory and your `package.json`

Comment: I have just updated the post with structure and `package.json`

Comment: How did you declare your `$PORT`?

Comment: In my index.js file, I am doing `server.listen(5000);`

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku doesn't use a static `$PORT` like the way you run your node app locally, you will have to make your `$PORT` dynamic port to enable heroku start the application listen on that any available `$PORT`

Change your `$PORT` to this:

```
// process.env.PORT lets the port be set by Heroku
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
```

Comment: Happy that I could be of help to you.